# Python Jedi roaming folder on windows 7

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, spyder

I am using anaconda 2/3 on Windows 7 and I have 4 Python environments.

in the roaming folder I see 3 folder appear:

> C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Jedi\Jedi\CPython-27-30
>   C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Jedi\Jedi\CPython-35-30
>   C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Jedi\Jedi\CPython-36-30

Is there any way to have those folders not in the Roaming profile?

thank you

Edit: as suggested by @Simon Fraser below I am using Spyder 3.2.4. There was an issue opened for Jedi about this in https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/926 but they say it's resolved and that they moved these folders to the local folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Jedi` package fixed this for Jedi 0.11.0 https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/commit/25133dc145a8a3ea82d54569026c1d0f979f6f63

But `conda` still does not have Jedi 0.11.0 for Windows (and no custom repos either). What I did was edit the file `/site-packages/jedi/settings.py` and change `APPDATA` to `LOCALAPPDATA` as is described in the link.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's a setting in [Jedi](https://jedi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/settings.html#filesystem-cache) (The module that gives your editor autocompletion hints) to move the cache directory.

```
jedi.settings.cache_directory = '/home/docs/.cache/jedi'
The path where the cache is stored.

On Linux, this defaults to ~/.cache/jedi/, on OS X to ~/Library/Caches/Jedi/ 
and on Windows to %APPDATA%\Jedi\Jedi\. On Linux, if environment variable 
$XDG_CACHE_HOME is set, $XDG_CACHE_HOME/jedi is used instead of the default 
one.
```

Since you're not using Linux, the environment variable won't help. Find where your editor has its settings for Jedi, and change that option (The question tag hints it might be Spyder, but you don't say for sure)

You may need to move the contents of that Jedi directory to the new location, if it doesn't work the first time, so don't delete them straight away

**Edit**: It looks like Spyder doesn't offer this configuration option - so if this affects you, you may need to modify spyder's source in [jedi_plugin.py line 50](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/master/spyder/utils/introspection/jedi_plugin.py#L50) where it already updates a jedi setting:

```
jedi.settings.case_insensitive_completion = False
```

Comment: Thank you @Simon. I am indeed using Spyder 3.2.4. It's actually not the `jedi_plugin.py` file. It's the /jedi/settings.py file.

There was an issue opened for Jedi about this in https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/926 they say it's resolved and that they moved these folders to the local folders. This has been done in https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/commit/25133dc145a8a3ea82d54569026c1d0f979f6f63